# add commas to Numbers without String manipulation

Tags: code-golf, number

This challenge consist in adding commas to numbers every `3` spaces like:

```
123456789 => 123,456,789
```

### Specifications:

- The possible inputs will be `1,000 <= input <= 100,000,000`
- You can ONLY use Mathematical Operators
- (*) You can NOT do string, array, index or character manipulation
- You can NOT use any kind of built-in functions that add these commas
- The zeros should remain, ex `10000 => 10,000`
- You need to print/alert/log the output (so "the output is at x
  var" is not allowed)

(*) the only exception is when forming/printing the output (but not in a manner that suggest cheating)

### Examples

```
10100 => 10,100
120406 => 120,406
999999999 => 999,999,999
```

---

**A basic idea on how to get numbers legally:**

```
n = 123456;
m = roundDown(n / 10);//even if ends with .9
d = n - m;//we get the last number
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is `123,45,6` acceptable output for the input `123045006`, or do we need to include the leading zeros? I'd assume we do, but if not, I have a very nice 13-char GolfScript solution. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen we need to use the zeros. I will clarify that (updating)

Comment: Integers only or will it have to support floats too?

Comment: @elssar you can use floats as long as they don't add the commas for you automatically or something like that

Comment: @ajax333221 : commas, by definition, involve a string op, since integers don't come with commas. you want to add commas without string ops ???? cuz even after doing all the division and modulo by 1000 still involves prepending or appending a 1-byte string `","` to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### GolfScript, <s>13</s> 37 chars

```
0:|;~{.10%|):|3%''','if@10/.9>}do]-1%
```

Look, Ma, no arrays!

Well, almost.  The pieces of the output are collected on the stack in right-to-left order, so the final `]-1%` is needed to reverse them.  But I assume that's OK, as it counts as "forming/printing the output".

Here's an ungolfed version with comments:

```
0 :| ;         # initialize the variable | to the value 0
~              # eval the input, turning it from a string into a number

{              # start of loop
  .            # duplicate the number on top of the stack; we'll need it later
  10 %         # take the remainder modulo 10 and leave it on the stack

  | ) :| 3 %   # increment | by one and take the remainder modulo 3 of the result
  '' ',' if    # if the remainder is 0, push a comma onto the stack, else an empty string

  @            # pull the value we saved at the start of the loop to top of the stack
  10 /         # divide it by ten, rounding down
  . 9 >        # check if the result is greater than 9...
} do           # ...and repeat the loop if so

]              # finally, collect the digits and commas off the stack into an array...
-1 %           # ...and reverse it for output
```

---

If it weren't for a few pesky details, the following 13-char solution would be pretty hard to beat:

```
~1000base','*
```

However, it fails on two counts: it doesn't correctly preserve leading zeros in digit groups, and the built-in base conversion operator `base` *might* be considered "array manipulation", since it takes a number and returns an array of digits.

---

Ps. Here's an older 49-char arrayless solution:

```
~{.999>}{:^1000%:&9&>99&>+{0}*','^1000/}while]-1%
```

Comment: you used an array. Using strings, character position, indexes or arrays is not allowed

Comment: `the only exception is when forming/printing the output`, the "collect digits and commas" is a formatting operation; no cheating to me. I'm developing a C interpreter of a language derived from GolfScript, which is able to interpret this solution; if you remove the array-related `]-1%` part,my lang will output the correct result since it by default "dumps" the stack from top to bottom (it seems to me more natural for a stack oriented lang);the point is that the result is ready, you need just formatting, and this must be allowed or very few solutions would be possible!

Answer (score 6):

You weren't very specific on the output format...

### Haskell, 56

```
reverse.takeWhile(>0).map(`mod`1000).iterate(`div`1000)
```

example:

```
GHCi> reverse.takeWhile(>0).map(`mod`1000).iterate(`div`1000)$93842390862398
[93,842,390,862,398]
```

Comment: I don't understand Haskell, but is that array-free?

Comment: As array-free as it gets. Only lazy lists, i.e. pointers to functions and to integers. – It also has the leading-zero-problem, though, that requirement came in after my post; I can't fix that without `String` objects. Or can I? Wait...

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 86 chars

I figured this warranted a different enough answer. The first answer is for 3.0 only because of the print statement with `end=`, and this answer because division automatically floors instead of converts to float, and the use of backticks

```
b=input()
k=0
x=''
while b>0:
 x=`b%10`+x;b/=10;k+=1
 if k%3==0and b>0:x=','+x
print x
```

Only string manipulation is building the output

edit: by adding 5 characters `int()`, this program can accept any integer, even above 1 billion. The previous program inserts `L`s (python longs) if the number is too large, but is still within the constraints of the challenge. Here is the program that works with any integer:

```
b=input()
k=0
x=''
while b>0:
 x=`int(b%10)`+x;b/=10;k+=1
 if k%3==0and b>0:x=','+x
print x
```

-

```
879612587634598623589762354009
879,612,587,634,598,623,589,762,354,009
```

Answer (score 2):

AWK, no strings, 84 chars:

```
{for(p=$0;.1<p/=10;++i);for(;i-->0;printf i&&i%3==0?"%d,":"%d",$0/10**i%10);print""}
```

Test runs:

```
% awk -f commas.awk <<< 1230
1,230
% awk -f commas.awk <<< 123012
123,012
% awk -f commas.awk <<< 12301 
12,301
% awk -f commas.awk <<< 12301000
12,301,000
```

Answer (score 2):

### C, 136

```
i,j,k;main(m,n){scanf("%d",&n);for(m=n;n^0;i++,n/=10);k=i%3;while(j++<i)printf("%d%c",(int)(m/pow(10,i-j))%10,j%3==k?',':0);putchar(8);}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you say `;n^0;` instead of just `;n;`?

Comment: In C, the `^` operator means xor, so it should evaluate to 0. In this case, with that context, the for loop should never run. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 2):

`awk`, 47 chars

> ```
> awk '{for(_=NF-2;1<_;_-=3)$_=","$_}NR' FS= OFS=
> ```

```
10,100
120,406
999,999,999
```

Comment: This is splitting the string into characters (`FS=`), and looping over character positions to insert `,`.  The rules for this question say no string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 82 chars

```
n=input()
x=''
while n>999:x=','+`n/100%10`+`n/10%10`+`n%10`+x;n/=1000
print `n`+x
```

I can get it shorter (67 chars) with

```
while n>999:x=',%03d'%(n%1000)+x;n/=1000
```

Not sure if that's legal.

Answer (score 1):

### befunge, 62

```
&# <v%3-\3%3y+8a$j*d`0:/a\%a:
1`j@>:3%\3/!3*j',,\'0+,1+a8+y
```

well this code is array free, since befunge itself is array free.

- the first line simply reads a number and push every digit into stack.
- the second line reads those digits and prints then once at a time. and put commas if needed.

note that if you are trying to run it using rcfunge, you need run using "-Y" option.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala 65:

```
def f(n:Int){if(n<1000)print(n)else{f(n/1000)
print("."+n%1000)}}
```

Testcode:

```
val l=List(1,12,123,1234,12345,123456,1234567)
l.foreach(x=>{f(x);println})
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript <del>104</del>, <del>99</del>, <del>90</del>, 81

> Edit: I just noticed I also have this missing zeros bug when any group of
>   contains 000 ,00X or 0X0. If you see this message, the code below isn't fixed yet

Code:

```
for(n=0,s="",i=m=1e3,r=0;i<n*m;i*=m)r=~~((n%i-r)/i*m),s=r+(i-m?",":"")+s;alert(s)
```

**Note:** change the value of `n` for different inputs

Comment: ah, I just noticed I also have this missing zeros bug when any group of contains like `000 ,001 or 010`... I will try to fix this later

Comment: I think the input should always count towards the final character count. at least the minimum: `n=0;` = 4 characters. I could reduce at least 6 characters in both my codes if input lines were free

Comment: @Blazer maybe you are right, I will update that. Sorry, this is my second code-golf :)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 165 chars

```
from math import*
b=int(input())
j=10**8
k=l=0
while j>0:
 z=int(floor(b/j));b-=z*j;k+=1;j=floor(j/10)
 if not l:l=z!=0
 if l:print(z,end=','if k%3==0and j>0 else'')
```

No strings except for '' and ',', no arrays/lists/tuples/dicts, or indexing

edit: nixxed some characters

Comment: Not sure how python works, but surely `int(floor(x))` is the same as `int(x)` or `floor(x)`? And if python is anything like the languages I use, you should be able to change `','if k%3==0and j>0 else''` to `''if k%3&j>0 else','` Also, I think `while j>0` can be changed to `while j`

Comment: @Griffin thought `int()` rounded to the nearest. I guess I'm still learning some small details about Python xD. python's `&` operator is bitwise, not logical, so it can't be used the same way all the time. the while thing was just me being a noob

Comment: `floor` is essentially truncating after the decimal point, depending on the language `int` will round or truncate. Either way doing `int(floor())` is no different from `floor()`. In javascript, because of the loose typing ORing by zero will truncate decimals: `AAA.BBB | 0 == AAA` - this might work for phython... My bad about the bitwise and, at least switch the if statement around so you don't need the `==0`

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.6.5, <s>65</s> 94 chars

```
n=input()
s=''
while n:
    s=','+str(x)+s if x else','+'000'+s
    n/=1000
print s[1:]
```

Just used the string to store the output.

<s>*Now preserves zeros</s>

Comment: does not preserve zeros. eg: 976235004 = 976,235,4

Comment: gah! back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 80 chars

Using recursion within `printf` to reverse the printing order (recursion handles the least significant digits first, but printing is done when returning, so they're printed last).

```
n;
p(x) {
    x=n%1000;
    n/=1000;
    printf(n?p(),",%03d":"%d",x);
}
main(){
    p(scanf("%d",&n));
}
```

Comment: You can shave off a few characters if you declare something like `v=1000` and use `x=n%v;` and `n/=v`.

Comment: @GigaWatt `,v=1000` costs 7 chars, saves 6. `,v=1e3` comes out even.